# Complex tables - commentry

Tags: tables, longtable, multirow

I have a table which I need to go over multiple pages, hence I am using `\usepackage{longtable}`.

However I am also using `\multirow` as my comments are simply too long to fit into one! But there are still issues....

So I have twiddled with it, but still no luck! Any help would be greatly appreciated. I need it so that I have row names and corresponding information. Similarity ideal needs to go across two rows. The comment must fit in the table!

So a Minimum working example is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\fancyplain{}{\today}}
\cfoot{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}


\begin{document}
 \maketitle

 \begin{longtable}[H]
 \caption{\label{labelname}Table Caption}
 \footnotesize

Painting    &   Lucien Freud, A Man and his Daughter, 1963-4.jpg    \\  
Comment & \multirow{3}{*}{  This painting is in the style of Lucien Freud.     Initially, the 3rd colour is significant. This is over Lucien Freud's 3rd significant     colour. The last attribute, the painting's contrast is greatly unbroken, when the image     is at a scaled to 20. There are either warm or cool colours but not both, so the image is not very varied. The contrast for this painting is very larger than Lucien Freud's.      } \\    
Similarity  & freud & 1.0   \\  
&    Bacon & 0.0    \\  
Classification  &   Freud   \\ \hline   

\end{tabular} \scriptsize \par}
\end{longtable}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you don't need `multirow`. Use the `p` column type. In addition, you had several mistakes in your code. Your corrected code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,headheight=\baselineskip]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\fancyplain{}{\today}}
\cfoot{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}

\title{Where are the mistakes?}
\author{redrubia}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{longtable}{cp{.65\textwidth}c}
\caption{Table Caption\label{labelname}}\\\hline
Painting    &   Lucien Freud, A Man and his Daughter, 1963-4.jpg  &  \\
Comment &   This painting is in the style of Lucien Freud.     Initially, the 3rd colour is significant. This is over Lucien Freud's 3rd significant     colour. The last attribute, the painting's contrast is greatly unbroken, when the image     is at a scaled to 20. There are either warm or cool colours but not both, so the image is not very varied. The contrast for this painting is very larger than Lucien Freud's.      & \\
Similarity  & freud & 1.0   \\
&    Bacon & 0.0    \\
Classification  &   Freud  & \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comparing this file with yours and finding the mistakes is left as an exercise.